# How to manage different versions of Java in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

How to manage different versions of Java in Ubuntu 14.04 like the way we use RVM for managing ruby versions?
It is currently difficult to manage projects running on different versions of java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java`
(optional if you want to start fresh)
-----> This would remove all pre-existing alternatives.

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java priority`
(`priority` could be the version number)
-----> This would create an alternative, you could add one for each version of java.

`sudo update-alternatives --config java`
-----> To select the alternative version you wish to 
                           use.

When you do this it will give you a list of Java versions to choose from , you choose based on the version number.